# Why is my Entity Framework 6.1 (Code-First) SaveChanges count higher than expected?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have noticed that the count returned from `DBContext.SaveChanges()` is higher than expected. I have an entity called `DocumentMaster` and an entity called `Workspace` which has a collection of `WorkspaceDocumentLink` entities, which are just a link `WS_id` to `DM_id`.

In my unit test I create one `Workspace`, 20 `DocumentMaster`, and 20 `WorkspaceDocumentLink` entities. When I call `context.SaveChanges()` I can see that the list of entities in `ChangeTracker.Entities()` contains the 41 added entities, as expected. Using Sql Profiler, I can see that the 41 insert statements are being issued, as expected, and nothing else. Note that there is nothing else being added, modified, or deleted in the context.

So I should have a count of 41 from `SaveChanges()` but I am seeing 81 each time. Given that the `Workspace` is the only unique entity type, it seems that the count for the others is being doubled.

The only thing that I can think of that might be affecting the count is that I have a `DbCommandTreeInterceptor` that replaces the insert clause with a new one containing the `CreatedBy` information:

```
interceptionContext.Result = new DbInsertCommandTree(command.MetadataWorkspace,
     command.DataSpace, command.Target, clauses.AsReadOnly(), command.Returning);
```

could this affect the count?

Comment: I would look for some hidden 40 updates, but it is just a shot into darkness.

Comment: Do you have any triggers on the affected tables?

Comment: No - no triggers. Also, I just removed my interceptors so that there is no other code running other than the EF SaveChanges and I see the same doubling each time, although the correct number of Sql statements are executed.

Comment: @Santhos Sql profiler is not filtering anything out and I do not see any other Sql statements. I'm going to raise it as an EF issue.

Comment: This really seems like a bug unless it is a "well documented behaviour" if you know what I mean :)